# run shell script from tk GUI

Tags: shell, tcl, tk-toolkit

I have have 5 different shell scripts which do data extraction from different log files, I have written a GUI in Tcl/Tk to consolidate all the scripts to an interface and have also made input entry widgets to provide folder locations to variables used in shell scripts where logs are stored , one thing that I didn't get a hold of is how to integrate my shell scripts with Tk GUI command buttons and display output in text widgets.

Any suggestions.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the shell scripts are fairly quick to run, the best method is to use `exec`.

```
# If the scripts are marked executable
set output [exec thescript.sh $argumentOne $argumentTwo]
```

```
# If the scripts are not marked executable (assuming that they're really bash scripts)
set output [exec bash thescript.sh $argumentOne $argumentTwo]
```

You can set up the arguments by binding an `entry` or `ttk::entry` widget to a global variable and using that, or you can use any number of other mechanisms. (There's a vast number of possibilities.) The output is placed in the `output` variable; you can display it by inserting it into a `text` widget:

```
set outputwidget [text .t]
# Remember to put this widget in the right place in your GUI!
#    pack $outputwidget

# Put the output in the widget
$outputwidget insert end $output

# Stop the user from editing the contents.
# Note that you need to change the state to normal from code to update it from your script
$outputwidget configure -state readonly
```

There are a lot more things you can do. There are additional options to `exec` that can help in some circumstances, there's whole possibilities for processing the text before showing it to the user, and there's many things you can do with tagging the text in the widget to do things like syntax highlighting, etc. Many of these things are complex enough that you'll need to as separate questions on them.

Also, if you have long-running scripts then you'll either be using a pipeline (created with `open |…`) or the (old but excellent) Expect package. These are also big topics in themselves.

Comment: Hi Donal , Thanks a lot for your reply , I am quite new to Tcl and was thinking to convert my scripts from bash to Tcl , I wanted some help in converting my shell script to tcl , I am really stuck and working on it for a while now. The script does some very simple task like extracting certain text from log files sorting it based on first column and presenting it in column form . Can you please help?

Comment: Hi Donal , Thanks a lot for your reply , I am quite new to Tcl and was thinking to convert my scripts from bash to Tcl , I wanted some help in converting my shell script to tcl , I am really stuck and working on it for a while now. The script does some very simple task like extracting certain text from log files sorting it based on first column and presenting it in column form . Can you please help?

Comment: Please see the question which shows the log.                                                    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44661199/tcl-script-to-extract-values-from-multiple-text-files-having-same-format-and-gen/44984939#44984939