# Extract information from a list using Tcl

Tags: tcl

I have multiple log files which contain values like this  with headers :

I want to make a header file which contains each row from column 1 as individual column headers and min - max from each of the row and present it in column format.

```
Info in log files: 

Trace Header                        Min         Max       Mean

aaa                                  1           6         xx
bbb                                  2           7         xxx
```

What I want :

```
aaa            bbb

1-6            2-7
```

Thanks for help

Comment: where do "aaa" and "bbb" come from?

Comment: Hi @glennjackman aaa and bbb are the strings in first column of the the log file aaa is col 1 row 1, bbb is col 1 row 2 . As seen in the code  which shows a small part of the log file. These are extracted from Trace headers of a Seg-Y file .

Comment: Hi @glennjackman aaa and bbb are the strings in first column of the the log file aaa is col 1 row 1, bbb is col 1 row 2 . As seen in the code  which shows a small part of the log file. These are extracted from Trace headers of a Seg-Y file .

Comment: You'll need to read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Thanks @glennjackman I read through the reference and realized the question was a bit cluttered , I have edited my question and removed the extra code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this (the long listing is supposed to be in the `data` variable, read from a file or whatever):

```
foreach line [split $data \n] {
    if {[scan $line {%s %d %d} header min max] eq 3} {
        set result($header) $min-$max
    }
}
% parray result
result(aaa) = 1-6
result(bbb) = 2-7
```

The scan command looks for three fields on each line, one text field and two decimal integer fields. A matching line reports three fields found, empty lines or lines with only text report less. If it finds a match, it is added to the result.

**ETA:**

To deal with the real-world log file you mentioned in a comment:

```
foreach line [split $data \n] {
    if {[scan $line {%59[ #()-./0-9:=>A-Za-z]%s %d %d} header stuff min max] eq 4} {
        set result([string trim $header]) $min-$max
    }
}
```

(Note that duplicate headers are compacted into one in the array.)

If you have whitespace in a field, you can't consume the data with `%s`. Instead you can find out what kind of data the header might contain by using

```
% set chars [string map {\n {}} [join [lsort -unique [split $data {}]] {}]]
 #()-./0123456789:=>ABCDEFGHILMNOPRSTUVWXY[]abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
```

which is easy to simplify to the field specification

```
[ #()-./0-9:=>A-Za-z]
```

If you need to able to match brackets, put them in like this:

```
[][ #()-./0-9:=>A-Za-z]
```

To split at lines containing uppercase text and blanks, then only equal-signs and possibly more blanks up to line end,

```
package require textutil::split
::textutil::splitx $data {(?n)^[[:upper:] ]+=+\s*$}
```

Documentation:
[eq (operator)](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/expr.htm),
[foreach](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/foreach.htm),
[if](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/if.htm),
[join](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/join.htm),
[lsort](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lsort.htm),
[package](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/package.htm),
[parray](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/library.htm),
[regexp](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/regexp.htm),
[Syntax of Tcl regular expressions](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/re_syntax.htm),
[scan](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/scan.htm),
[set](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/set.htm),
[split](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/split.htm),
[string](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/string.htm),
[textutil::split (package)](http://core.tcl.tk/tcllib/doc/trunk/embedded/www/tcllib/files/modules/textutil/textutil_split.html)

Comment: thanks for the reply, I just had one more road block and I am trying to get my head around is how to divide this big log file in multiple sections to extract the headers , I want to split the log files where there is indentation with "========", I have tried split but it gives strange result. See log : http://textuploader.com/dlgk5

Comment: thanks for the reply, I just had one more road block and I am trying to get my head around is how to divide this big log file in multiple sections to extract the headers , I want to split the log files where there is indentation with "========", I have tried split but it gives strange result. See log : http://textuploader.com/dlgk5

Comment: @AbhishakeYadav: the easiest way is to use `textutil::splitx` from the standard library Tcllib. See example.

Comment: Thanks Peter Lewerin . appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

Code snippet:

```
set foo  {
Info in log files:

Trace Header                        Min         Max       Mean

aaa                                  1           6         xx
bbb                                  2           7         xxx
}

set pattern {^(.*)\s+(\d+)\s+(\d+)\s+.*$}
set result [regexp -line -inline -all -- $pattern $foo]
array set bar {}
puts "Here's one view..."
foreach {all item min max} $result {
    puts "$item $min-$max"
    set bar([string trim $item]) $min-$max
}
puts ""
puts "Here's another one..."
puts [join [lsort [array names bar]] "\t"]
foreach item [lsort [array names bar]] {
  puts -nonewline "$bar($item)\t"
}
```

Execution output:

```
Here's one view...
aaa                                  1-6
bbb                                  2-7

Here's another one...
aaa bbb
2-7 1-6
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @sharad , you are a life saver , I was trying to convert one of my shell scripts to tcl which does this job, also writing a gui in tk to do everything but I am completely new to tcl so had no clue how to do it. I might ask you some more questions if I feel in doubt. Thanks Again , cheers

Comment: Thanks a lot @sharad , you are a life saver , I was trying to convert one of my shell scripts to tcl which does this job, also writing a gui in tk to do everything but I am completely new to tcl so had no clue how to do it. I might ask you some more questions if I feel in doubt. Thanks Again , cheers

Comment: Hi @Sharad some how the script is now working and gives error when I run it on logs , I guess it's due to regexp, can you please see the exaple log in one of the previous questions I posted :    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44661199/tcl-script-to-extract-values-from-multiple-text-files-having-same-format-and-gen

Comment: Note that the headers are disconnected from the values in the second example.

Comment: The regexp above is for the question above. You'll have to change it for the log file sample you're providing. You may instead choose a simple approach to traverse the data in the log file line by line (split data on "\n") and then divide it into columns (simple split of regexp based) and then filter out specific columns using lindex.

Comment: @Sharad the log is part of a bigger file want to divide the log in different parts seperated by "=======" can you please help.   log :  http://textuploader.com/dlgk5

Comment: @Sharad, note Peter's comment. You also need to lsort for the foreach loop.